# PhantomJS with selenium doesnt scroll to bottom

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

With Firefox driver, the below code works(scrolls to bottom of page) but not with PhantomJS webdriver. The below page has infinity scroll so I need to scroll down to gather more information. Kindly help me identify why this doesnt work with phantomjs.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.betpawa.co.ke/upcoming")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.events-wrapper"))) 
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'),"html.parser")
print len(soup.findAll("div", {"class":"prematch"}))
```